# Unable to pass values to PreparedStatement - last fifth argument is skipped

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the following problem. I have the method which use the query to check if there is any reservation for given place in time from Start to End to check if the user can book this place in given time then returns Ture of False. My problem is that every time my ResultSet is equal to null. I do debug step by step and all variables are properly passed. With the debugger, I found that after passing 4 arguments (2nd-time start date) the fifth is skipped and myRs value remains null. Also, the 4th argument after passing is underlined with the green line but no communication is displayed. I am using Netbeans. I have no idea whats going on. Here goes my DBUtil method code:

```
public boolean doesBookExist(int number, Date start, Date end) throws Exception {

    boolean result = false;

    Connection myConn = null;
    PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;

    try {
        // get a connection
        myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

        // create sql for validation
        String sqlValidate = "SELECT * FROM `rezerwacje_miejsc`"
                + " WHERE `NR_MIEJSCA`=?"
                + " AND (`START` BETWEEN ? AND ?"
                + " OR KONIEC` BETWEEN ? AND ?)";

        myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sqlValidate);

        myStmt.setInt(1, number);
        myStmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(start.getTime()));
        myStmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(end.getTime()));
        myStmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(start.getTime()));
        myStmt.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(end.getTime()));

        // execute query
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sqlValidate);

        // check if there was a match
        result = myRs.next();
        return result;
    } finally {
        // close JDBC objects
        close(myConn, myStmt, myRs);
    }
```

Comment: For one thing, you have mis-matched backticks (you have one after `KONIEC` but not before it). I'd expect the statement to fail entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sqlValidate);
```

It should be just:

```
myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();
```

The version of `executeQuery` accepting a string is a holdover from [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) (API design problem). You want the one without parameters, which is [provided by `PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--).

---

There's also a typo in the query that I assume must just be in the question, not the real code: You have mis-matched backticks (you have one after `KONIEC` but not before it).

Comment: Thank you, sir, so much, everything seems to be up and running! I'll remember the lesson! :)